# Read Assembly Code and Multiply the Value

Tags: assembly, arm

now I am learning about ARM code

```
STMFD SP!, {R4-R6,R10,R11,LR}
ADD R11, SP, #0x10
MOV R5, R0
MOV R4, R1
CMP R5, #0
BNE loc_10E348C
MOV R0, #0
BL sub_3D31B4
```

From above assembly code (ammo), anyone could give me more about the detail what the function? I have read many article on google but still can't figure it out I just need an teacher to teach me and what should I do to multiple the value of the ammo in the game from above assembly code?

Thank you

Comment: Show what you've figured out so far (with links to relevant resources), then ask specific questions.

Comment: How about downloading and reading the instruction set reference first? https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/latest/

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very difficult to look at raw assembly with no comments and figure out what it's supposed to do. While you've given a little background that it has to do with managing the player's ammo, there's really no way to know which registers are being used for what. I can't look at the code itself and tell which register represents the current ammo, max ammo, etc. Based on the fact that it doesn't push ```R0-R3``` and adds the stack to ```R11```, this code was most likely written by a C compiler so I would look at the C source code instead.